Springdoc's GroupedOpenApi together with external Swagger urls seem to not be working
I want to combine internal application's OpenAPI spec with external specs into one single Swagger UI in Spring Gateway application
According to contributor of Springdoc library, it should be possible:

If you want to combine in the same swagger-ui both, REST APIs that are
deployed within the same application as the swagger-ui and external
REST APIs: This is an enhancement and will be available with the next
release: v1.2.22.
To achieve that, you declare your REST APIs that are deployed within
the same application as the swagger-ui using GroupedOpenApi. And you
external REST APIs with the following syntax:
SwaggerUiConfigProperties.addGroup("group1", "url1");
SwaggerUiConfigProperties.addGroup("group2", "url2");


Basically I have one application called 'Microservice' that has OpenAPI spec generated by Springdoc and exposed at localhost:8081/v3/api-docs
I then have a Spring Gateway application that defines external Swagger url to Microservice and Gateway has routes to rewrite url to it. It works fine until I add GroupedOpenApi bean to include another group with Swagger documentation that is deployed in Gateway application itself. If I add GroupedOpenApi bean, the Swaggers from external urls no longer work. Any ideas how to combine external and internal Swagger with Springdoc?
Sample code:
@SpringBootApplication
public class GroupedOpenApiBugApplication {

    @Autowired
    private SwaggerUiConfigParameters swaggerUiConfigParameters;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GroupedOpenApiBugApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .routes()
            .route("First service Open Api", ps -> ps
                .path("/v3/api-docs/microservice")
                .filters(gatewayFilterSpec -> gatewayFilterSpec.rewritePath("^.*$", "/v3/api-docs")
                )
                .uri("http://localhost:8081")
            )
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi groupedOpenApi() {
        swaggerUiConfigParameters.addGroup("microservice", "Microservice");
        return GroupedOpenApi
            .builder()
            .group("internalservice")
            .packagesToScan("com.example.GroupedOpenApiBug")
            .build();
    }

//  Comment GroupedOpenApi Bean above and uncomment PostConstruct to get external OpenAPI spec working
//  @PostConstruct
//  public void postConstruct() {
//      swaggerUiConfigParameters.addGroup("microservice", "Microservice");
//  }
}


I think you should ensure that your internal and external API groups are defined independently. Specifically, external API groups should be added using SwaggerUiConfigProperties, while internal APIs are managed with the GroupedOpenApi bean. Also make sure that the internal and external Swagger groups have unique names. In your setup, it seems like the name "microservice" might be used both internally and externally, which can be the real culprit.

I think I do define it independently. External API group: is using swaggerUiConfigParameters for 'microservice' group. Internal API group is usign GroupedOpenApi with 'internalservice' group.
